# Login failed for User when using Database connection in Owin Startup class

Tags: sharepoint, owin, add-in, hangfire, provider-hosted

I am using Hangfire in my sharepoint provider hosted app. I have Owin Startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"), Cron.Minutely);
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();            
    }
}
```

I have initialised defaultConnection in my `web.config` file. Everytime i run, i get error saying `Login failed for Domain\MachineName`, I tried passing user id and password in connection string, but still is fails saying login failed for that user.

Can anyone help me to find the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a sql authentication login credential in my SQL server. I passed the created user id and password in my connection string.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DEESS01CW0184CO\SPQ11CONTENT;Initial Catalog=HangfireTest;User ID='testuser';password='testuser123'" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[image]

The issue still persisted for windows authentication.